# Need a simple explanation of javascript execution context

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, executioncontext

I am just trying to figure out a simple explanation of execution context work flow.

-- code

```
var a=10;

function sample(){

   var y = 10;

};
```

--

- Javascript engine starts.
- Global execution context is created.
- Lexical and Variable environment objects are created.
- This property is created. Points to global object.
- Environment objects( lexical and variable ) has environment record and
  outer properties. Can anyone help by explaining the difference of
  environment objects in this context.
- Creation phase scans the code variables are hoisted for global
  context.
- Environment record inside Environment object ( lexical or
  variable ??) keeps the variable definitions.
- It scans the code for functions and finds sample function. What happens 
  when it finds a function ? Is the [[scope]] property set now ?? Would be 
  great if someone can give a clear explanation of [[scope]] property
- Execution phase for global execution context is started.
- Reaches function sample.
- Sample function context is created.
- Similar steps as above happen in creation phase.
- An execution context is created(
- Lexical and variable environment is created)
- Lexical environment has an environment record and outer environment
  which points to global lexical environment.
- Variable environment is also created with similar properties.
- Variables are hoisted.
- Any change happens to [[scope]] property now ??
- Execution enters execution phase.  and so on.

Please note : I kind of understand that explanation and behaviors changes when there can be a function expression or try catch clause etc. Have read that variable environment comes into play during such situations. I am just looking for the work flow for the above function. Even the arguments for functions create an argument property. That also can be ignored. Just a very simple explanation of lexical,variable environment and [[scope]] property based on above sample code. There is also a this property. In this case it is just global object - Window for both contexts, I believe. Lets ignore that too to keep things simple :). After understanding this may be I will create a separate question for that :).

Hope someone can help me in understanding this basic concept. Looking for an ES5 based explanation. Thank you for your help in advance.

mia

Answer (score 0):

Javascript would do variable hoisting when you use var in your code.

```
var a=10;

function sample(){

   var y = 10;

};
```

So compiler would translate your above code to following. The variables would be hoisted to the top of their scope.

```
var a=undefined;
a=10;

function sample(){
  var y=undefined; // this is because var is function scoped in javascript
  y=10;
};
```

Also say you have following code.

```
var a=10;

if(true){
  var b=20;
}
```

The above code would be translated by compiler to-

```
var a=undefined;
var b=undefined;

    a=10;
    if(true){
       b=20;
    }
```

Comment: thanks @Harkirat Saluja for your explanation. I understand hoisting.  I am actually looking for some internals like [[scope]] property and lexical enviornment and their relation.